# how to use python variable in oracle procedure as dynamic variables

Tags: python, sql, stored-procedures, cx-oracle

`I have sql procedure and I have some python variables I want to run this procedure along with using this variables as dynamic`

```
`  I have sql procedure and I have some python variables I want to run this procedure along with using this variables as dynamic ` 

CREATRE OR REPLACE PROCEDUE SQURT_EN_UR(
v_ere       IN MIGRATE_CI_RF %TYPE,
V_efr       IN MIGRATE_CI_ID%TYPE,
v_SOS       IN MIGRATE_CI_NM %TYPE,
V_DFF       IN MIGRATE_CI_RS%TYPE, )
BEGIN
UPDATE MIGRATE_CI
SET RF= v_ere 
ID=V_efr  ///I WANT YOU VARIABLE HERE 
NM= v_SOS   ///I WANT YOU VARIABLE HERE
RS= V_DFF ///I WANT YOU VARIABLE HERE

WHERE CO_ID=V_efr_id;
if(sql%rowcount=0)
THEN
INSERT INTO MIGRATE_CI 
(ere,
efr,
SOS,
DFF,
VALUES(v_ere ,
V_efr,
v_SOS,       
V_DFF,
upper(assign_tr),
upper(assign_mod),
END IF;
END SP_MIGRATIE_DE;
/
```

```
`i want to create a function like this to use my varablie as dynamic ones in procedure`

try:
        # create a connection to the Oracle Database
        with cx_Oracle.connect(cfg.username,
                            cfg.password,
                            cfg.dsn,
                            encoding=cfg.encoding) as connection:
            # create a new cursor
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                
                # call the stored procedure
                cursor.callproc('SQURT_EN_UR')
                return cursor.callproc('SQURT_EN_UR')
    except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
        print(error)

#my variables is 
V_efr ="r55" #I WANT YOU VARIABLE HERE 
NM= "dree"   #I WANT YOU VARIABLE HERE
RS= "ssyt" #I WANT YOU VARIABLE HERE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the parameters directly to the procedure, as in this:

```py
cursor.callproc("SQURT_EN_UR", [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4])
```

Replace the values of arg1, arg2, arg3, and arg4 with your own variable names or constants -- whatever you need!

Comment: yeah but how to match btween variables names and names in procedure

Comment: The example I gave was by position -- so the first argument in the procedure is matched by the first argument in the array of arguments you pass.